# Getting error when adding one python repo to another python repo as a submodule

Tags: python

I have two separate Python code repos A and B. Currently code in repo B runs as a stand-alone process (running on Linux). I need to add code repo B under code repo A as a submodule so that code A depends on code B. For this purpose I have checked out code B repo under code A (B is a subfolder under A).
But when I invoke a method in code B from inside a method in code A, I run into a lot of dependencies errors e.g. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'".
Is there way to keep the code in repo B unchanged but to make it work both as a stand-alone process and as a dependent code inside code A.

Comment: How about installing it with pip? `pip install git+https://repo-url.com/project.git@{version}`

Comment: Use absolute imports in code B or add its directory to `sys.path` in code A

Comment: Added like this in a file in cCode A. Code B directory name is "emailparsing".
`sys.path.append('/home/user/git/emailparsing')
from emailparsing import ApiParsing`

Getting still the same error:
from emailparsing import ApiParsing
ImportError: cannot import name 'ApiParsing' from 'emailparsing' (unknown location)